# Solving a differential equation with colored Gaussian noise

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, random

I'm trying to reproduce the following equation:

[image]

With $ n(t) $ defined as:

[image]

Assuming $ g_A=g_B=1 $ I tried using `NDSolve` but struggle with the last term representing the colored Gaussian noise. The best thing I can come up with is using a normally distributed white noise as the last term in equation A1 above, but this seems not to be correct:

```
  v[t_] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]
s = NDSolve[{10 r'[t] == -4 r[t] (r[t]^2 - 1) - 2*1 (r[t] - 1) - 
      2*1 (r[t] + 1) + n[t], 
    n'[t] == -(n[t]/100) + 0.7 Sqrt[2/100]*v[t], r[0] == 0, 
    n[0] == 0}, {r[t], n[t]}, {t, 0, 100}];
```

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: You will have to re-cast your system in terms of a random process. Have you seen this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30558/solving-a-stochastic-differential-equation ?

Comment: Thanks! I browsed through some of the answers involving random processes, but it seems I can use the `Itoprocess` function only with a Wiener process but not with an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. I'm not familiar with random process though, so it might still work, but don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Lotus suggested, I think [`RandomFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomFunction.html) and [`ItoProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ItoProcess.html) are what you need.

```
τ = 1;
ga = gb = 1;
σ = 0.7;
τs = 100;

sol = RandomFunction[ItoProcess[{
  \[DifferentialD]r[t] == \[DifferentialD]t/τ*(-4 r[t] (r[t]^2 - 1) - 2 ga (r[t] - 1) - 2 gb (r[t] + 1) + n[t]),
  \[DifferentialD]n[t] == -n[t]/τs \[DifferentialD]t + σ Sqrt[2/τs] \[DifferentialD]w[t]
  }, {r[t], n[t]}, {{r, n}, {0, 0}}, {t, 0}, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]], {0, 100, 0.01}];

ListLinePlot[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Does this look right?  I haven't used these functions much myself, so this is a learning experience for me too!

Comment: Thank you, that looks similar to the results of the article. I tried it like this myself and it seems it is only possible to use a Wiener process in this function, although the authors formulate some Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, as in equation A1. I'm gonna wait a bit longer, maybe someone can figure it out, because I have no idea ;).

Comment: @holistic The OU process for `n` given by eqn. A1 is included in the `ItoProcess`. Simultaneously solving for `r` and `n` means `r` is driven by a OU process (the gold trajectory), unless I'm missing something.

Comment: oh I'm sorry, I must have overlooked that, you are right! Then it's all fine, awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the definition of `v[t]` and got this:

```
Clear[t]
v[t_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 0.7], t]
s = NDSolve[{10 r'[t] == -4 r[t] (r[t]^2 - 1) - 2*1 (r[t] - 1) - 
      2*1 (r[t] + 1) + n[t], 
    n'[t] == -(n[t]/100) + 0.7 Sqrt[2/100]*v[t], r[0] == 0, 
    n[0] == 0}, {r[t], n[t]}, {t, 0, 100}];
Plot[Evaluate[r[t] /. s], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t", "r[t]"}]
Plot[Evaluate[n[t] /. s], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t", "n[t]"}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had similar results, but this does not seem to be correct, since the results should fluctuate over time and it seems NDSolve cannot handle this random part somehow :(