# Using RandomVariate in a NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, random

I want to solve a version of the Langevin's equation using RandomVariante with a normal distribution. Therefore, I used the next code:

```
f = NDSolve[{
DAF12'[t] == 1+Sqrt[2]RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 5]]-DAF12[t],
DAF12[0] == 0},
DAF12[t],
{t, 0, 10}]
```

Then, a ploted the solution:

[image]

I was waiting much more variation in the solution, but it looks very smooth. So, I was wondering if each of the points of the solution takes the same random number. How can I know this? and How should I write the code in such a way that each point of the solution has a different random number?

Comment: Yes, the random number is evaluated once and that number is used throughout.  Look up `ItoProcess` for instance or stochastic differential equations in the documentation/help center in Mathematica.

Comment: It's possible to write it as an Itō or Stratonovich process but Mathematica will not necessarily solve it. For example: `proc = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]X[
     t] == (Sqrt[2] \[DifferentialD]W[t] - X[t]) \[DifferentialD]t, 
  X[t], {X, 0}, t, W \[Distributed] WienerProcess[10, 5]]` followed by `RandomFunction[proc,{0,1,0.01}]` will not produce any paths. It's possible I got something wrong though - have a look at these related questions and search for Langevin: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23183/72682 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23183/72682